# How Do You Print A Specific Line Of A Text File?

Tags: php

I have a program that searches a text file to see if a certain string is in that file, which I have gotten to work fine. What I need to know is how to print a particular line of that text file. For example, if the file lists three street names each on its own line, and the program searches for one of them, I would want it to print out only the line that has that street name on it.

If the file looked like this: and the word being searched for was `Rose Road`,
I want it to only print out `6784 Rose Road`

```
4543 Drock Drive
1254 HeadHill Road
6784 Rose Road
```

This is what I have so far, which checks if it's in the file, but I am just unsure how to print out a particular line.

```
$roadName = "Rose";
$handle = fopen("streets.txt", "r");
if(strpos(file_get_contents("streets.txt"),$roadName) !== false) //Checks to make sure its in the file.
{
    echo fgets($handle); //This is what I was trying, but it only prints the 1st line.
}
```

Comment: You could use a regex. Maybe something like https://regex101.com/r/xwzlgZ/2/... or you could use `strpos` and `substr` but you won't know if it is a partial match with that.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` and `strpos` have no effect on the file handle, so `fgets` just read from the beginning of the file.

You can read each line with `fgets`, test if it matches the string, and then print it.

```
while ($line = fgets($handler)) {
    if (strpos($line, $roadName) !== false) {
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
}
```

If the file is very large, this is better than the solution that uses `file_get_contents`, because it doesn't have to read the entire file into memory and then create a huge array of all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would explode the lines into an array and the check every line:

```
$roadName = "Rose";
$file=file_get_contents("streets.txt")
if(strpos($file,$roadName) !== false) //Checks to make sure its in the file.
{
  $lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$file);
  foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line,$roadName) !== false) echo($line);
}
```

Comment: If you are going to create an array, just use `file()`.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$line_contains = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'Text Want Search') !== FALSE) {
         $line_contains[] = $line;
    }
}
$line_contains_print = implode("\n", $line_contains);
print $line_contains_print;
```

Actually I use above code to remove line that contains a text. Like this,

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$exclude = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'want to remove') !== FALSE) {
         continue;
    }
    $exclude[] = $line;
}
$rm_match_line = implode("\n", $exclude);
print $rm_match_line;
```